# When to accept an answer after somebody puts a bounty on my question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I've had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658846/angular-ui-router-urlrouterprovider-when-not-working-anymore) on here for a few months that has gone unanswered. In the process of writing the question, I tried something new that got me around the problem, but it still left the question itself unanswered.

Fast forward to this week, it was given a bounty by somebody and now  has an answer to the original question!  I took a look at it, and as far as I can tell, their answer is good!  I'm happy to accept it.  Mind you, I'm not working on that project anymore, and I can't actually test this out on the actual code, so I'm not 100% sure about it working for the situation I posted it in.

I also want to consider the fact that if somebody else has put a bounty on this, they are likely looking for an answer to a similar problem they have, and so I want to make sure that this answer works for them because I would feel bad if I accepted the answer, it *didn't* work for them, and they were left stuck and with a loss of rep or whatever.

I looked into contacting this user, to ask them if they were happy with the answer, but there is no way to do that.  I also thought about just commenting, saying something like "Hey, I like this answer to the question I asked, but I'm gonna wait for this bounty guy to speak up to make sure he's cool with it first...", but decided it felt kind of out of place since it really contribute to the question and was due to my ignorance.

So that's why I'm here! I'd like to know the general etiquette/protocol in this kind of situation.

Comment: Even if you don't have their name, if you left a comment like:  "BountyOfferer I'm no longer working on what I asked this question for and can't verify that the what Answerer posted works.  Did it work for you?" prior to the bounty being awarded, you'd have a very good chance of the person who posted the bounty seeing your question.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. If you accept it, any other answers that may work for the bounty offerer will still be there too

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should accept whatever answer you feel best solves the problem for you.  Don't focus on what answer best meets another user's bounty criteria.  They're able to award the bounty to whatever answer they wish, regardless of which answer you accept.

Comment: Ahh!  I wasn't aware bounties could be awarded outside of the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It won't even matter then.  If *the person who started the bounty* accepts an answer then that answer will automatically receive the bounty if it is not awarded.

Comment: @Servy I didn't know that the accept needs to come from the starter. Thanks!

Comment: @mykepwnage That's one of the *main* uses of bounties. To give some credit to answers that provide particular insights, even though they aren't required for the most useful answer. This is especially done when an answer delves deeply into a specific aspect of the question instead of the whole question.